# Are Pig "lead" and "lag" not limited by "window_start" and "window_end"?

Tags: apache-pig

It seems that function "lead" and "lag" of "Over" are not limited by window_start and window_end

This is my data:

> cat    1
>
> cat    2
>
> dog    1
>
> cat    3
>
> cat    4

This is my script:

```
DEFINE MY_OVER org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over;
DEFINE MY_STICH org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch;
A = load '/user/user1/temp/test_over' using PigStorage() as (animal:chararray, number:int);
B = GROUP A BY (animal);

C = FOREACH B {
    C1 = order A BY number;
    GENERATE FLATTEN( MY_STICH( C1, MY_OVER(C1.number, 'lead',0,1,2,0) ) );
}


DUMP C;
```

The result when DUMP is:

> (cat,1,3)
>
> (cat,2,4)
>
> (cat,3,0)
>
> (cat,4,0)
>
> (dog,1,0)

The result proves that "lead" is not limited by window_start, and window_end. But i can't find that note anywhere in the document: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html

My question:

Is it true that "lead" and "lag" are not limited by window_start, and window_end ?